# Arduino AnalogWrite and its frequency and effectiveness

Tags: arduino, pwm

Reading about the arduino analogWrite function I have come to understand that it uses PWM for the variable DC voltage. (by controlling the width of the pulse)

However how do we control the frequency of the pulse? I came across a few articles about the same but couldn't get them. Any help is appreciated.

Moreover how effective is it to use that analogWrite voltage as say a biasing voltage? Or maybe as a variable Vcc itself. Does the fact that DC is obtained via PWM will effect underlying circuitry expected working (where the underlying circuitry is anything one can do with a transistor)

Answer (score 3):

Changing PWM frequency is not directly supported by Arduino command set, but it can be done. For this you need to know a couple of things:

- find the datasheet for the exact microcontroller (ATmega..) that is on your Arduino
- which Arduino pin you want PWM frequency to change;
- which pin on the controller it is connected to (this is described on http://arduino.cc/ );
- find the chapter on PWM in the datasheet that discusses the controller pins you are interested in.

On top of that, some of the PWM pins are attached to timer0, which is heavily relied upon for other system tasks (like `delay();`). So fiddling with PWM *may* change the execution speed of some code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... Is there any library (3rd party) that can abstract this procedure and document the consequences of the same. Plus is delay() the only function that is affected? Because usually I avoid using delays anyway, so that wont be much of an issue.

Comment: Don't know, never really studied that part of Arduino.

Answer (score 2):

The frequency of the pulse can be controlled by direct manipulation of the timer control registers. The details vary quite a bit depending on what timer and what pin you’re using. Some pins allow fine grained control of both frequency and duty cycle, while others only allow controlling one or the other. For many applications (e.g. LEDs), the exact frequency does not matter as long as it’s high enough.

Ultimately, a PWM signal behaves quite differently from a true analog signals. For some applications, e.g. controlling LEDs, a PWM signal is *more* convenient than true analog (i.e. relationship of PWM duty cycle to brightness), but for the applications you mention (biasing voltage), PWM is not really suitable.

Comment: Can you exemplify few applications where you need variable frequency PWM? Also, in that case how do we get different logic levels from arduino?

Comment: One case I can think of is IR signal generation, where a number of different frequencies are commonly used (38kHz, 40kHz).

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean by “logic level”; I assume you mean duty cycle, i.e. fraction of time the PWM signal is “on”. For some PWM outputs, this can be specified separately, for others it cannot.

Answer (score 0):

The [Arduino PWM frequency library](http://code.google.com/p/arduino-pwm-frequency-library/downloads/list) works excellently. The library is a third party open source contributed library, not part of the standard distribution.

There is a forum discussion including library documentation and update history [here](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?topic=117425.0).

I have used this library extensively, no complaints.

---

Regarding obtaining variable DC from PWM, the standard technique is to use a low pass filter: at the simplest, a resistor and capacitor.

The lower the corner frequency of this filter, the slower it will respond to PWM duty cycle changes, but the lower will be the ripple on the output, given a PWM frequency significantly higher than the corner frequency.

Conversely, to reduce ripple and yet have responsive DC output, a higher PWM frequency would be used - along with a higher cut off frequency for the low pass filter.

The ripple contribution also increases with higher load current, so to counter that higher frequencies are used, as well.